# Calculating TCP retransmission in Soalaris 10 using netstat -s

Tags: tcp

I am using "netstat -s -P tcp" to calculate retransmission. The output shows that tcpRetransBytes is more than  tcpOutDataBytes. Three servers show this-- all are up for about a month. Is there any bug ? Note that if I use the command "netstat -s -P tcp 6" then I see tcpRetransBytes is less than tcpOutDataBytes.

I have a feeling that tcpOutDataBytes counter is reset while tcpRetransBytes keeps accumulating since the last reboot.

I cannot show the output of the command at the moment. Any help will be appreciate, PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. tcpOutDataBytes is kept in a 32-bit integer. This is why when the value goes above 4255151339 or there about it starts again from 0. It's really shame that it is happening in Solaris 10